# Giving Custom permission

Tags: sharepoint

My requirement is that there are 2 parties 
1. User (who creates the item)
2.Approvers who approve the item

When the user creates the item then they should see only their created item in the list (This is easily possible)...the approvers should have only read access and they can see all the items ...when i select the option that only person who creates the item can see the item then approvers are not able to see the items...can somebody plz help that how to work with this...maybe i am missing some simple stuff so can anybody just point me out to the solution..

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you want the Approvers group to be able to approve the item then they need at least the Approver permission assigned to their group, not just read-only (otherwise they can't update the item to mark it as approved).

However, since the requirement is also that users should only see their own items, I believe the only way the Approvers will also still see the items, is if they have Full Control permissions on the list, therefore you need to break permission inheritance at the list level.